# Finding the velocity of a particle using conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

> This question investigates how motion in a planet’s gravitational field can be
>   assumed to be motion under a constant force.The force experienced by a particle of mass $m$ in a planet's gravitational field along the z-axis, where $G$ is a constant is 
>   $$F = -\frac{GmM}{z^2}$$
>   If at time $t = 0$ , the particle has zero total energy, using energy conservation, find the velocity $\dot r = \dot r (t)$ at subsequent times t.

Here is what I have done so far.

So using a conservation of energy :
$$E(t) = T(t) + V(t) = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + mgh$$

We have acceleration vector :
$$\vec{a}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -g\end{pmatrix}$$

thus we have a velocity vector :
$$\vec{v}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}v_{0}\cos(\theta) \\  - gt\end{pmatrix}$$

so if t = 0 :

$$\vec{v}(0)=\begin{pmatrix}v_{0}\cos(\theta) \\  0\end{pmatrix}$$

Am I on the right track? one of my classmate told me I should not be solving this problem in this way. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no indication that the particle was launched at an angle.  If the question is *exactly* what you have written, I think the intention is that the motion is one dimension.   I'm with your friend.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. Yes the question is exactly what I have written. If the motion is one dimension do I still use the E(t)= V(t)+ T(t) getting little confused here...

Comment: You are not giving enough information on the problem. What does the angle   θ mean?

Comment: @freecharly Forget about the angle.  The OP started thinking about this is two dimensions, but that was a mistake, I think.

Comment: There really should be more clarification in the statement of the problem.  It doesn't say what potential the particle finds itself in.  Gravitational near the earth?  Gravitational far from the earth? An arbitrary potential?  Zero potential?  But you can make progress assuming $0=1/2mv^2+mgh$.  I'm not sure what the writer of the question has in mind.

Comment: Apologies to everyone who commented. I think this question is an extension of the previous question I was working on. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(t)=T(t)+V(t)$ is sort of on the right track, but looking into acceleration etc. is not. Instead, just stick with the energy conservation expression you are working on  and continue with it. For starters, set it equal to zero, because the question clearly states that initial energy is zero.

But, remember that you should use the general formula for potential energy:

$$V(t)=-\frac{GmM}{r(t)}$$

and not $V(t)=mgh$, now that we are far from Earth. I believe you in the end can solve for an expression for velocity.